# Retrieve Route Parameters in any Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Suppose my URL looks something like this:

```
/blog/[post_id]/something
```

What is the recommended way to pass `$post_id` down to any component anywhere in the tree?

I know how to retrieve route parameters using [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) but passing the values down is always giving me a hard time.

For [pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) I could technically use React Contexts although this seems a bit oversized for such a trivial use case.

For [layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) I am honestly completely lost because pages are children of layouts and the return value of [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) is passed to the page and not the layout.

My components could make use of [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) but this requires `useEffect` and would also make my component depend on the route itself...

Any advice would be welcome (:

Answer (score 0):

> My components could make use of `useRouter` but this requires `useEffect` and would also make my component depend on the route itself...

`useRouter` seems like the obvious solution here.  I'm not exactly understanding your concerns regarding the component depending on the route.  I guess it does make the `Layout` less flexible since it needs to know that the post id is stored in the `post_id` query variable.  But I would do it anyways :)  It gives you a nice and simple way to access the query variables which can be used in a `Layout` that's outside of your `BlogPost` or in a deeply-nested component that you use inside the `BlogPost`.

Using the [per-page layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts) approach:

`/components/Layout`

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>You are viewing post id #{router.query.post_id}</h3>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

`/pages/blog/[post_id].jsx`

```
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';

export default function BlogPost() {
    return <div>Hello World</div>
}

BlogPost.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return (
        <Layout>
           {page}
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

`/pages/_app.tsx` (to support per-page layouts, copied from docs)

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and the cleanest way is to use `window.location.pathname`. this will give you the part after the domain name. for example for

```
http://localhost:3001/blog/[post_id]/something
```

you will get `/blog/[post_id]/something`

```
const pathname=window.location.pathname
const splittedPathname=pathname.split("/") // ['', 'blog', '[post_id]', 'something']

const dynamicId=splittedPathname[2]
```

you can run above code in `useEffect` and set a state. or you could write a hook and use it in the components that under dynamicId components

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const usePathname = () => {
  const [postId, setPostId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const pathname = window.location.pathname;
    const splittedPathname = pathname.split("/");
    const dynamicId = splittedPathname[2];
    setPostId(dynamicId);
  }, []);

  return { postId };
};

export default usePathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for client side rendering, `useRouter` is the best way to go. If you are looking for SSR or SSG, you should rather use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.